# Validação de inputs não atualiza

Tags: javascript, html

Eu fiz a seguinte função:

```
function verifica(){
    var csenha = document.getElementById("csenha").value;
    var csenha2 = document.getElementById("csenha2").value;
    if(csenha != csenha2){
        document.getElementById("csenha2").setCustomValidity("As senhas são diferentes.");
        csenha2.setCustomValidity('');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Ela é pra confirmar a senha, e funciona, caso elas estejam diferentes ele retorna falso para o formulário e impede o submit, mas mesmo quando eu altero elas pra ficarem iguais, continua entrando na condição do if e alertando que são diferentes. Quero saber como faz pra isso parar de acontecer. O HTML está assim:

```
  <label for="senha"><b>Senha</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Insira sua senha." id="csenha" required>

  <label for="senha-repeat"><b>Repita a senha</b></label>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Insira sua senha novamente." id="csenha2" required>
```

Chamado da função:

```
<button type="submit" onclick="return verifica()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="signin">Cadastrar</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem um erro na linha abaixo:

```
csenha2.setCustomValidity('');
```

O valor da variável `csenha2` é o valor do segundo campo, e não o campo em si.

Mesmo assim sua validação ainda estará incorreta.

É preciso ainda um outro evento que apaga o `setCustomValidity` quando o segundo campo for alterado, senão irá continuar mostrando a mensagem mesmo se senha forem iguais.

E remova também o `return` do `onclick` e coloque apenas `return` na função quando as senhas forem diferentes. Não precisa de `return false` porque esse click não precisa esperar um retorno booleano porque o `setCustomValidity` não estará vazio e o formulário não será enviado. Basta um simples `return` para sair da função.

Seu código ficará assim:

```js
function verifica(){
   var csenha = document.getElementById("csenha").value;
   var csenha2 = document.getElementById("csenha2").value;
   if(csenha != csenha2){
      document.getElementById("csenha2").setCustomValidity("As senhas são diferentes.");
      return;
   }

   document.getElementById("csenha2").setCustomValidity('');
}

document.getElementById("csenha2").oninput = function(){
   document.getElementById("csenha2").setCustomValidity('');
}
```

```html
<form action="./">
   <label for="senha"><b>Senha</b></label>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Insira sua senha." id="csenha" required>
   
   <label for="senha-repeat"><b>Repita a senha</b></label>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Insira sua senha novamente." id="csenha2" required>
   <br>
   <button type="submit" onclick="verifica()" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="signin">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Eu fiz do jeito que você disse, e agora ele trava o submit até que as senhas sejam iguais, mas não aparece mais o aviso da primeira linha.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta como vc está chamando a função verifica().

Comment: Pronto, está feito.

Comment: Alterei o código novamente... não é preciso do `else`.